# How to apply HTML options in Rails Select Form Helper with Single Dimensional Array

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, forms

I tried to follow the Rails documentation on how to use the select form helper, and came up with this:

```
<%= f.select :datatype, options_for_select(%w(string select text)), prompt: 'Select a datatype', class: 'chosen-select' %>
```

This works with now errors, however the HTML options (in this case for the class specification) doesn't get applied. I've also tried using `html: {class: 'chosen-select'}`, which also didn't error (but didn't work either).

This produces:

```
<select name="some_object[datatype]" id="some_object_datatype">
<option value="">Select a datatype</option>
<option value="string">string</option>
<option value="select">select</option>
<option value="text">text</option></select>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`class` is being treated as part of the `options` argument:

`select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}`

Enclose the prompt in braces to fix:

```
<%= f.select :datatype, options_for_select(%w(string select text)), {prompt: 'Select a datatype'}, {class: 'chosen-select'} %>
```

Comment: Spot on! Thanks...after I saw your answer i was like ahhhh, of course...how frustrating.

Comment: Yup - it sure did.